# SSL Certificate Expires

Tags: ssl, big-ip

My idea of the SSL communication is a bit hazy and I needed some clarifications.

Architecture of my application - Internal Machine which has the application running is exposed to internet via a BIG IP server.

The certificate hierarchy on my website - Root (expires in 2040) R - Intermediate( expires in 2036) I - xxxx.com (expires in 2 days) F

I have the new certificate created with the same root and intermediate CAs. It is created with a different key. I also have the key.

My questions are :

1) When I perform a HTTP Post using a stand alone application from computer X (some random machine on internet) onto the exposed URL, the SSL handshake should occur at two places. a) Computer X and BIG -IP b) BIG-IP and the internal machine that has the application running. The standalone application should have the public certificates of the URL i.e., R and I, in its key store. Correct? Or should I have the xxxx.com certificate as well i.e., F as well? Who decides this?

2) This is a different scenario. I have placed the newly created certificate of xxxx.com (it has same Root and Intermediate certificates R and I) on the BIG IP server. The start period of this certificate is 1st Aug 2014. My internal instance, although, still has the old certificate. It expires on 3rd Sept 2014. I am able to post successfully even in this scenario. Why is it so? Since the keys are different for the new and old ones, the requests should fail during the SSL handshake of BIG-IP and Internal instance.

Kindly help me understand these two scenarios. I will be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Off topic here, but (1) depends on whether or not SSL terminates at BIG IP or whether it relays to your server via SSL. In either case the client needs to trust BIG IP, not your server. (2) The fact that the keys are different is irrelevant, and the fact that it succeeds suggests that this leg is plaintext. NB You didn't need a new key or even a new CSR, just a new signature over the same CSR as before.

Comment: OK. I get more clarity now. I have another related doubt though. Say there is https communication to occur between A and B. A posts onto B's https URL. The SSL handshake begins by B sending its public certificates to A. B's website has two CAs (root and intermediate) and the final *.com certificate. 'A' should typically contain the root and intermediate certificates in its cert bundle. But I am seeing few URLs which respond only when the final certificate (*.com) is also placed in A's wallet. Who decides this? B's application SSL settings?

Answer (score 0):

The root CAs should be in the client machine's trusted certificate repository. The server (BIG-IP) should have the intermediate cert and the cert for the fqdn (or SAN/wildcard) if you are offloading. If you are offloading at the BIG-IP and not re-encrypting to the origin server, then you don't need any certificates on the origin server. If you are, then it would be the same setup as the BIG-IP with intermediate and server cert.

In the event your intermediate and server certs are signed by a root NOT trusted by your client (internal certs or custom clients without the standard trusted CAs), you'll need to make sure your clients install the root CA manually or push it.